# Foreach loop not working

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have 2 foreach loops and both of them work by themselves (when the other is commented out).. but when I stick them together only the first one works....

```
// Splits the RichTextBox up so the numbers can be formatted properly.
String[] myXLines = calculateXRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
String[] myYLines = calculateYRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

// Converts the numbers to only contain 2 decimal places.
foreach (string decimalXLines in myXLines)
   removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) + "\n");

foreach (string decimalYLines in myYLines)
   removedYDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalYLines), 2) + "\n");
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work or why it's not working properly (the RTB does not append the text)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

### ***EDIT:***

```
    private void calculateXAndYPlacementOne()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                // Save the contents of the placementOneListBox into the file.
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");

                foreach (object item in placementOneListBox.Items)
                    sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());

                sw.Close();
            }

            // Catches an exception if the file was not saved.
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not write to file.");
            }

            // Reads the lines in the file to format.
            var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");

            // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
            var fileList = new List<string>();

            // Adds each line in the file to the list.
            var fileLines = "";
            while ((fileLines = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                fileList.Add(fileLines);

            // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
            var xyResult = new List<string>();
            var xResult = new List<string>();
            var yResult = new List<string>();

            // Iterate over each line in the file and extract the x and y values
            fileList.ForEach(line =>
            {
                Match xyMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");
                if (xyMatch.Success)
                {
                    // Grab the x and y values from the regular expression match
                    String xValue = xyMatch.Groups["x"].Value;
                    String yValue = xyMatch.Groups["y"].Value;

                    // Add these two values, separated by a space, to the "xyResult" list.
                    xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[] { xValue, yValue }));

                    // Add the results to the lists.
                    xResult.Add(xValue);
                    yResult.Add(yValue);

                    // Store the old X and Y values.
                    oldXRichTextBox.AppendText(xValue + "\n");
                    oldYRichTextBox.AppendText(yValue + "\n");
                    try
                    {
                        // Calculate the X & Y values (including the x & y displacements)
                        double doubleX = double.Parse(xValue);
                        double doubleXValue = double.Parse(xDisplacementTextBox.Text);
                        StringBuilder sbX = new StringBuilder();

                        sbX.AppendLine((doubleX + doubleXValue).ToString());

                        double doubleY = double.Parse(yValue);
                        double doubleYValue = double.Parse(yDisplacementTextBox.Text);
                        StringBuilder sbY = new StringBuilder();

                        sbY.AppendLine((doubleY + doubleYValue).ToString());

                        calculateXRichTextBox.AppendText(sbX + "");
                        calculateYRichTextBox.AppendText(sbY + "");

                        // Removes the blank lines.
                        calculateXRichTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(calculateXRichTextBox.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        calculateYRichTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(calculateYRichTextBox.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);

                    }

                    // Catches if it fails
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Could not calculate the X & Y values.");
                    }
                }
            });

            // Splits the RichTextBox up so the numbers can be formatted properly.
            String[] myXLines = calculateXRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
            String[] myYLines = calculateYRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

            foreach (string decimalXLines in myXLines)
                removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) + "\n");

            foreach (string decimalYLines in myYLines)
                removedYDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalYLines), 2) + "\n");


            for (int theLine = 0; theLine < placementOneListBox.Items.Count; theLine++)
            {
                string replacement1 = calculateXRichTextBox.Lines[theLine];
                while (replacement1.Length < 7)
                    replacement1 = " " + replacement1;

                placementOneListBox.Items[theLine] = ((string)placementOneListBox.Items[theLine]).Remove(20, 7).Insert(20, replacement1);

                string replacement2 = calculateYRichTextBox.Lines[theLine];
                while (replacement2.Length < 7)
                    replacement2 = " " + replacement2;

                placementOneListBox.Items[theLine] = ((string)placementOneListBox.Items[theLine]).Remove(29, 7).Insert(29, replacement2);

            };
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not manipulate the data properly.");
        }

        File.Delete(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");
    }
```

### ***See the below answer to see the code for the fix***

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: @Erno: Sorry, By **It's** I mean only one of the *removedXDecimalRichTextBox* is working.. the **Y** one does not work (meaning it does not append the text) in the format above but if I switched the foreach loops around the Y would work and the X would not..

Comment: Did you step through the code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: just  dropped your code into a test app, and it worked fine, no exceptions being thrown on yours? You're just using the Rich Text Box Control right?

Comment: @Erno: I have not.. I am not really familiar with stepping through it in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Put the cursor on the first line and press F9. The press F5. When the yellow cursor/line appears you can step through the code with F10. Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MasteringInDebugging.aspx

Comment: @Curtisk: I am doing a lot of data manipulation. Not sure why it is not working for me. I believe I am just using the RTB control.

Comment: Apparently the error is not in the code you posted. It probably is in the data you have in the textboxes. Until we see that code we can hardly help.

Comment: @Erno: I will repost function above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I fixed the problem by replacing the original code with this code:

```
            // Splits the RichTextBox up so the numbers can be formatted properly.
            String[] myXLines = calculateXRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
            String[] myYLines = calculateYRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
            int counterX = 0;
            int counterY = 0;

            foreach (string decimalXLines in myXLines)
            {
                if (counterX == 0)
                    removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) + "");

                if (decimalXLines != "" && counterX != 0)
                {
                    removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");
                    removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) + "");
                }

                counterX++;
            }

            foreach (string decimalYLines in myYLines)
            {
                if (counterY == 0)
                    removedYDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalYLines), 2) + "");

                if (decimalYLines != "" && counterY != 0)
                {
                    removedYDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");
                    removedYDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalYLines), 2) + "");
                }

                counterY++;
            }
```

Comment: the best practice is using Environment.NewLine instead of '\n' or "\r\n"

Comment: @Viacheslav: Okay, I have changed the '\n' to **Environment.NewLine** but am curious on why that is the best practice?

Comment: because some operation systems has different line end constant, by using the Environment.NewLine constant you will negate that issue

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you break each one out into multiple statements?  You're doing a Convert.ToDouble() and a Round() all inline with the AppendText() call.  Are you sure each step is behaving correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the input data, each time when an input string is not a correct number the call of the Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) will throw exception. If that code working in the background thread you will not receive critical exception.

In my mind the last element of the String[] myXLines = calculateXRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n'); is a empty string.

You can try to add the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries into split code:

```
String[] myXLines = calculateXRichTextBox.Text.Split(new []{'\n'},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but this is workaround, not a 100% woring solution.

Comment: That does not seem to work either. I also tried removing the extra lines by using: ***int counter = 0;
                foreach (string decimalXLines in myXLines)
                {
                    if (decimalXLines != "" && counter != 0)
                        removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");


                    removedXDecimalRichTextBox.AppendText(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(decimalXLines), 2) + "");

                    counter++;
                }*** but that also did not work..